# IOS JSON parsing into an objectkey

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm trying to implement the "Checking Duplicate Username" first of all, I have to get my json which stored all the record of my users. and get the object which is the username. Then matching them with the text from the UItTextField. My problem is that I can see all my json but I can't seems to parse it correctly.

```
-(IBAction) ChkUsername: (id) sender {
    NSDictionary * userdata = [NSDictionary new];
    [DIOSUser userGet: userdata success: ^ (AFHTTPRequestOperation * operation, id response) {
        NSLog(@"%@", response);
        DIOSSession * session = [DIOSSession sharedSession];
        [session setUser: [response objectForKey: @"user"]];
        NSDictionary * uname = [
            [session user] objectForKey: @"name"];
        if ([self.txtUsernameRegister.text isEqualToString: uname]) {
            // if([uname isEqual:self.txtUsernameRegister.text]){
            NSLog(@"You cannot use this Username");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"You can use this username");
        }
    }
    failure: ^ (AFHTTPRequestOperation * operation, NSError * error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];
}
```

I also got this error NSCFArray objectForKey:]

Edit here is how my JSON looks like.

```
{

uid: "60",
name: "pae1344",
mail: "viper1344@gmail.com",
theme: "",
signature: "",
signature_format: "plain_text",
created: "1396189622",
access: "0",
login: "1396189622",
status: "1",
timezone: "Asia/Bangkok",
language: "",
picture: "0",
init: "viper1344@gmail.com",
data: null,
uri: "http://localhost/drupal/rest/user/60"
},
```

Comment: i think you should check [response objectForKey:@"user"] . it must be NSDictionary

Comment: Quote the *entire* error message.  If it was `[NSCFArray objectForKey:] unrecognized selector` then that means you're trying to do `objectForKey` on an NSArray.

Comment: U are parsing the username to a nsdictionary when it should be a nsstring

Comment: I got it fixed now Thank you very much guys. instead of using the objectforkey, I used valueforkey instead. + some changes.